# Presentation for $H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, poincare-duality

Let me preface this with saying that I'm not a math student, but rather, a physics student and I'm trying to learn algebraic topology on my own.

I would like to determine the following:

Let $H_*(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}\langle [p] \rangle \otimes \langle [\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1] \rangle$ where $p$ is a point and $[p]$ and $[\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1]$ are fundamental classes. Let $a,b \in H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^*)$ be Poincare-dual cohomology classes, respectively. Then how can I write a presentation for the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1)$? I am struggling with where to begin with this. How should I proceed?

Also, is there an easy way to determine $H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1 \times \ldots \times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1)$ where there are $n$ copies of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Do you know  about the Kunneth formula?

Comment: Not prior to asking this question, but I just read it on Wikipedia though. Is it a straightforward application of the theorem?

Comment: It is a straightforward consequence of Kunneth. It might be better to call the cohomology classes in $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^2)$, $1$ and $x$ since the class in degree $0$ is the mulitplicative unit. Then the cohomology ring of a product of two is generated in degree $0$ by $1$, in degree $2$ by $x_1$ and $x_2$ and in degree $4$ by $x_1x_2$. Because these are even degree classes, there are no extra signs in the cohomology ring.